# LoginPath containing HashBang not redirecting properly

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using cookie authentication in MVC5, and I have a login path which contains a hashbang, like so:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/#!/Login"),
    Provider...etc etc
}
```

Unfortunately, when a user gets redirected to this login path, they get directed to an escaped version of it resulting in a 404 error, I see the following in the browsers developer console:

```
GET http://localhost:27431/%23%21/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Faaa%2Fbbb 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm assuming I have made a basic error somewhere but am not sure what it is, can anybody tell me?

Thanks

Comment: correct your loginpath as.... LoginPath = new PathString("/Login")

Comment: @Exception That isn't my login path though, it's *#!/login*, as in I want to go to the */login* route of the SPA hosted at the root of the application

Comment: new PathString("/#!Login")...just remove a extra "/" in PathString...

Comment: No better sadly @Exception, MVC is trying to redirect to an escaped version of the LoginPath, I need it to unescape the string before sending it to the browser, is this possible?

Comment: try using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode()....then...

Comment: When would I use this? This is happening at the point an unauthenticated user tries to access an Action method protected by **Authorize** and ASP.Net redirects them, it's giving the browser an escaped string.

Comment: Your SPA should be able to figure out if the user is logged in or not. So just redirect to the SPA without the hashbang and have the JavaScript load the `/login` route if the user isn't logged in.

Comment: Did you ever get an working answer on this, I too would like to know how to get PathString to not encode the '#' in a Url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no ideal but creating a dummy MVC Controller Action and then redirecting allowed me to redirect to a url with the '#!' in it.

eg. in the CookieAuthenticationOptions

```
LoginPath = new PathString("/LoginRedirect")
```

Action

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LoginRedirect(string returnUrl)
{
  return this.Redirect("/#!/Account?" + returnUrl);
}
```